# C# dictionary order of combinations

Tags: combinations

I need to iterate, for some values of k, on all [combinations](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Lexicographic_and_colexicographic_order) of taking k items out of a vector V containing N items. For example if N = 6 and k = 3 then I have to call F() on items V[1](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Lexicographic_and_colexicographic_order), V[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233125/0-1-knapsack-like-the-set-of-all-non-contained-affordable-binary-selections/236836#236836) and V[3], then on items V[1](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Lexicographic_and_colexicographic_order), V[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233125/0-1-knapsack-like-the-set-of-all-non-contained-affordable-binary-selections/236836#236836) and V[4], ending with V[4], V[5] and V[6].

Now, going through all combinations of the index is easy. Say k = 3 and N = 6. Then the first element can go from 1 to N-(k-1), the second from 2 to N-(k-2), the k'th from k to N (i.e. N-(k-k)).

So, for k = 3 the loop would be:

```
for (uint a = 1, a <=  N-2, a++)
  for (uint b = a + 1, b <= N-1, b++)
    for (uint c = b + 1, c <= N, c++)
     F(V[a], V[b], V[c])
```

and, for k = 4, the iteration would be:

```
for (uint a = 1, a <=  N-3, a++)
  for (uint b = a + 1, b <= N-2, b++)
    for (uint c = b + 1, c <= N - 1, c++)
       for (uint d = c + 1, d <= N, d++)
          F(V[a], V[b], V[c], V[d])
```

The question, however, is: **How do you accomplish this k-level nesting for an arbitrary k without hard coding it (or using code generation)?**

**Edit**: For background (a.k.a. THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK :)) please see Hans Engler's answer to my Math Stackexchange quesion:
[0-1 knapsack like - the set of all non-contained affordable binary selections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233125/0-1-knapsack-like-the-set-of-all-non-contained-affordable-binary-selections/236836#236836)

**Edit**: I'll provide a sample. Suppose V= {1,2,3,4,5}.

For k=2 I want F to be called in the following order: F(1,2), F(1,3), F(1,4), F(1,5), F(2,3), F(2,4), F(2,5), F(3,4), F(3, 5) and F(4,5).

For k=3 I want F to be called in the following order: F(1,2,3), F(1,2,4), F(1,2,5), F(2,3,4,), F(2,3,5), F(3,4,5)

Comment: Doing your own homework may mean you actually learn something about the problem at hand.#

Comment: I must admit I don't fully understand the problem, but it sounds like your need a recursive function for the solution. Just pass in the value of `k` and anything else that is different between the loops.

Comment: @ChrisBint I wish I was young enough to even have homework :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code samples are generating unique combinations, not permutations.  Combinations are unique regardless of order.  For example, if your data looks like this - 123, 231, 321 then you would be working with permutations.  Combinations fall under the domain of the binomial coefficient.

I have written a class in C# to handle common functions for working with the binomial coefficient.  It performs the following tasks:

1. Outputs all the K-indexes in a nice format for any N choose K to a file.  The K-indexes can be substituted with more descriptive strings or letters.
2. Converts the K-indexes to the proper index of an entry in the sorted binomial coefficient table.  This technique is much faster than older published techniques that rely on iteration.  It does this by using a mathematical property inherent in Pascal's Triangle.
3. Converts the index in a sorted binomial coefficient table to the corresponding K-indexes.  I believe it is also faster than older iterative solutions.
4. Uses [Mark Dominus](http://blog.plover.com/math/choose.html) method to calculate the binomial coefficient, which is much less likely to overflow and works with larger numbers.
5. The class is written in .NET C# and provides a way to manage the objects related to the problem (if any) by using a generic list.  The constructor of this class takes a bool value called InitTable that when true will create a generic list to hold the objects to be managed.  If this value is false, then it will not create the table.  The table does not need to be created in order to use the 4 above methods.  Accessor methods are provided to access the table.
6. There is an associated test class which shows how to use the class and its methods.  It has been extensively tested with 2 cases and there are no known bugs.

To read about this class and download the code, see [Tablizing The Binomial Coeffieicent](http://tablizingthebinomialcoeff.wordpress.com/).

The following code will iterate through the set of combinations in order:

```
int N = 6;  // Total number of elements in the set.
int K = 3;  // Total number of elements in each group.
int[] V = new int[N]; // Holds the vector of numbers.
// Create the bin coeff object required to get all
// the combos for this N choose K combination.
BinCoeff<int> BC = new BinCoeff<int>(N, K, false);
int NumCombos = BinCoeff<int>.GetBinCoeff(N, K);
int[] KIndexes = new int[K];
// Loop thru all the combinations for this N choose K case.
for (int Combo = 0; Combo < NumCombos; Combo++)
{
   // Get the k-indexes for this combination.
   BC.GetKIndexes(Loop, KIndexes);
   // Do whatever processing with the V array that needs to be done.
   // Code to print the values out in C#:
   String S = V[KIndexes[0]].ToString() + ", " + V[KIndexes[1]].ToString() + ", " + 
      V[KIndexes[2]].ToString();
   Console.WriteLine(S};
}
```

You should be able to port this class over fairly easily to the language of your choice.  You probably will not have to port over the generic part of the class to accomplish your goals. Depending on the number of combinations you are working with, you might need to use a bigger word size than 4 byte ints.

Comment: Great answer: Theoretical explanation + code that actually works. It's not sorted as I need it, and I still haven't figured out the magic of converting Pascal Triangle to combinations (the linked article is all about Poker, which I don't play) but I'll manage. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This does smell like Homework, [which is ok](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), but you should indicate that it is homework.

In any case, when you see yourself diving into a series of loops without a clear end, it's likely that recursion will help.  Consider the class below.  I'll leave the guts of the function F() empty, but point you down a reasonable path (I think):

```
class Program
{
    private void F(int[] vector, int k)
    {
        if (vector.Length > 0)
        {
            // TO DO: operate on the first k elements of vector
            // Question: what conditions will throw an exception?
            Console.WriteLine("now operating on vector of length: " + vector.Length);

            // Re-define vector and re-apply F()
            vector = vector.Skip(1).Take(vector.Length - 1).ToArray();
            F(vector, k);
        }

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] vector = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
        int k = 3;

        try
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.F(vector, k);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception: " + ex.Message);
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.Write("Any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ain't homework, ain't homework. See link at to math stackexchagne for a full real-life-problem description. OK, so I'm old and rusty, but calling the class "Homework" is a little rubbing it in.

Comment: OK, a little ego-saving re-formatting.  I'll leave the homework disclaimer so that SO veterans don't kill me.

Comment: Great. Could you take a look at my edit, describing the desired call sequences? I'm not sure the question was clear enough...